# Radio button background image with css

Tags: html, css

So Im trying to style my radions buttons with a background image so the entire radio button is just an image. When the button has been pressed I want to change the url of the background image. Is this possible?

HTML

```
   <form method="POST" action="scripts/rate.php">
            <label for="star" class="star">
            <input type="radio" name="rating" value="star1">
        </form>
```

CSS

```
  input.star
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}

label.star
{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image: url('star-grey.png');
}
```

Comment: Did you even have tried, or searched it, before you asked the question?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have you made any attempts yet? Do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
<input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" checked="checked" />
<label class="radio" for="r1"></label>
```

Hide by css your radio buttons:

```
.radios input[type=radio]{
    display:none
}
```

And style the label as you want to. I created a simple jsfiddle that fully demonstrate how to use your radio buttons without having the default look. Instead, it is jut a little colored square that changed when it is checked.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTADZ/)